# I want to open the appropriate window depending on whether the user is authenticated or not. Firebase Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication, navigation

I want to open the appropriate window depending on whether the user is authenticated or not.
But now an error appears for a second
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
and then the map does not open even though the user is authenticated.

"start" it is a variable that is initialRoute

Here is my code.

```
void main() => runApp(App());

String start = "";

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete((){
      FirebaseAuth.instance
          .authStateChanges()
          .listen((User user) {
        if (user == null) {
          print('User is currently signed out!');
          start =  '/';
        } else {
          print('User is signed in!');
          start =  '/map/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid}';
        }
      });
    });
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    return FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return MyApp();
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your default firebase app like below;

```
  Future<void> initializeDefault() async {
FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
assert(app != null);
setState(() {
  loading = false;
}
);
print('Initialized default app $app');


}



 @override
  void initState() {
    initializeDefault();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    super.initState();
  }
```